# Generate heatmap with color as amount of instances between two intercepts

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, data-science

I have a lot of data that is barely interpretable by bare sight as an xy-scatter plot. For mit it is more intereseting where clusters where built this is why I have chosen the idea of an heatmap:

```
heatmap, yedges, xedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(10,10))
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
```

generates the following plot

[image: false heatmap]

which is quite alright. However I'm not sure what this color even indicates but it's not the amount of datapoints between a certain range (e.g. `4>x>5 & 11>y>12`).

**The question**

I know I could write a program that merges appropriate datapoints, count the instances for a cell and draw the desired heatmap by my own, but isn't there already an implementation of such a neat tool in data science?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to type it on my own, here is for all who look for a rudimentary solution ([thanks to](https://gist.github.com/teechap/9c066a9ab054cc322877)). As desired with the X- values in the center of a block:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def makeOwnHeatMap(x,y,bins):
    #shift +/- for the axes labels and 
    xMin = float(int(min(x)))-0.5
    xMax = float(int(max(x)))+0.5
    yMin = float(int(min(y)))-0.5
    yMax = float(int(max(y)))+0.5
    yStep = float(yMax-yMin)/bins[0]
    xStep = float(xMax-xMin)/bins[1]


    downscaledGraph = np.zeros((bins[0],bins[1]))

    #make heatmap
    for i in range(0,len(y)):
        curY = y[i] #current y-value from data
        curX = x[i] #current x-value from data

        yetY = 0 #current y compare value within a stepsize
        yetX = 0 #current x compare value within a stepsize
        cntY = 0 #counter y for matrix coordinates
        cntX = 0 #counter x for matrix coodrinates
        while (yetY < curY-yMin):
            yetY += yStep
            cntY += 1

        while (yetX < curX-xMin):
            yetX += xStep
            cntX += 1

        #ends up with incrementing 1 x too much
        cntY -= 1
        cntX -= 1

        downscaledGraph[cntY,cntX] += 1


    #make axes labels
    xbar = []
    ybar = []
    thisY = yMin
    while thisY <= yMax:
        ybar.append(thisY)
        thisY += yStep

    thisX = xMin
    while thisX <= xMax:
        xbar.append(thisX)
        thisX += xStep

    #draw heatmap
    xbar, ybar = np.meshgrid(xbar, ybar)
    intensity = np.array(downscaledGraph)
    plt.pcolormesh(xbar, ybar, intensity)
    plt.show()


    for i in range(0,bins[0]):
        for j in range(0, bins[1]):
            print downscaledGraph[i,j],"\t",
        print "|"
    print "_______"
```

here the result.

[image: final result]

and

```
0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     |
0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     |
1.0     0.0     12.0    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     |
18.0    0.0     7.0     0.0     0.0     16.0    0.0     0.0     |
8.0     0.0     7.0     0.0     0.0     10.0    0.0     1.0     |
15.0    0.0     6.0     0.0     0.0     12.0    0.0     7.0     |
0.0     0.0     3.0     0.0     0.0     3.0     0.0     6.0     |
0.0     0.0     4.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     |
0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     |
0.0     0.0     2.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     |
```

Note: I can't guarantee if it's priting right results. Use the lineprint to verify its correctnes

Answer (score 1):

you could use matplotlib hexbin for a straightforward approach, or check the kde plots in seaborn. I am not sure I follow your comment about the counts. Do you think they are misplaced? Due to matrix orientation differences with other languages, there is often confusion about origin of axis or the need to transpose the matrix. Other than that, the 2D bin at ~(8, 12) should have about 14 elements, as given by the color bar.